# Tooltip bottom left position bootstrap4

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to position my input field tooltip on bottom left so it's perfectly aligned with the input field. Not sure if it matters but the page contains many input fields which are dynamically generated.

Tried using `offset` parameter but I think it's a bit buggy when it comes to zoomed content and that `+11` correction could be pain ass in the when coming up with a general solution.

```
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({
    placement: "bottom",
    title: "test"
    offset: -$('#inputFieldId').width()/2 + 11
});
```

I've also tried modifying `transform` style of the `.bs-tooltip-bottom` class and it works really nice! The problem is that the tooltip flickers for a bit between original bottom position and new bottom left position. Plus I think this could be done a lot easier I just can't figure out how.

```
$('#inputFieldId').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
    var x = $('#inputFieldId').offset().left;
    var y = $('#inputFieldId').offset().top + $('#inputFieldId').height();
    $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('transform', 'translate3d('+x+'px, '+y+'px, 0px)');
})
```

About the flickering problem, what I've tried so far is changing the `opacity` of the tooltip before being show to 0 and show it when my custom transformation is set. But it still flickers.

css:

```
.tooltip.show {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

js:

```
$('#inputFieldId').on('show.bs.tooltip', function () {
    $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('opacity', '0');
})

$('#inputFieldId').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
    var x = $('#inputFieldId').offset().left;
    var y = $('#inputFieldId').offset().top + $('#inputFieldId').height();
    $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('transform', 'translate3d('+x+'px, '+y+'px, 0px)');
    $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('opacity', '0.9');
})
```

UPDATE:

The `.bs-tooltip-bottom` doesn't actually exist in the `show` event, hence the `opacity` workaround doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sincerely hope there is an easier solution but this is working for me. Everything apart from listening for `inserted` event instead of `show` (`inserted` is `triggered` after `show` and before `shown`) and added css is same as stated in the question.

css (optional):

```
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^="bottom"] {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

js:

```
$('#inputFieldId').on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function () {
    $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('opacity', '0');
});

$('#inputFieldId').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
    var x = $(this).offset().left;
    var y = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();

    $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('transform', 'translate3d('+x+'px, '+y+'px, 0px)');
    $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('opacity', '0.9');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the flickering effect add a delay to show.

**For example:**

`$('#inputFieldId').tooltip({delay: { "show": 140, "hide": 0 }});`

For the flickering to be completely gone the show has to be delayed to at least 140. The opacity change is actually not necessary either.

```
   $('#inputFieldId').tooltip({delay: { "show": 140, "hide": 0 }});
   $('#inputFieldId').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
        var x = $(this).offset().left;
        var y = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
   $('.bs-tooltip-bottom').css('transform', 'translate3d('+x+'px, '+y+'px, 0px)');
    });
```

Comment: The bellow (accepted) answer solved all the issues without adding any delays.

Comment: It does. Just wanted to post something that solved the "flickering". I even used the accepted answer and the flickering was still there.

Comment: Oh, didn't have that problem. Cool, yeah better to post it for future uses :)